# X3D don't recognise <rectangle2d>

Tags: x3d

When I use `<Rectangle2D />` node, the rectangle did not display on canvas, and the debug console print a warning `WARNING: Unrecognised X3D element <rectangle2d>.`. I try it with Chrome 67 and Firefox 61, and my code is as follow:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>X3DOM page</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.js'></script> 
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.css'></link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <X3D width='500px' height='400px'>
            <Scene>
                <Shape>
                    <Appearance DEF='MagentaAppearance'>
                        <Material diffuseColor='0 1 0' />
                    </Appearance>
                    <Rectangle2D ccw='true' lit='true' size='7,7' solid='true'></Rectangle2D>
                </Shape>
            </Scene>
        </X3D>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, use `x3dom-full.js` instead of `x3dom.js` for the 2d geometries.